# How do I get line numbers in a unity headless server's stack trace?

Tags: unity, server, debugging

For some reason Unity 5 doesn't allow me to do a developement build of a headless server, and this is quite a problem when debugging, since I get stack traces without line numbers, such as:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at ClientServer.Update () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Trying the [xvfb trick](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/353653/can-a-unity-game-be-started-over-ssh.html) to run a pseudo-headless server, which doesn't prevent enabling debugging symbols, doesn't work (it crashes mono for some reason).

I'm really at a loss on how to debug an headless server… is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://forum.unity.com/threads/exception-with-filename-unknown-and-no-line-number.449449/